# How to take BigDecimal value in database and make it human readable in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bigdecimal

I want to show prices for products, and read that using Decimal is far more reliable than Integer or using Floats.

I would like to know how to extract the actual number 17.99 from the database when it is stored as `<BigDecimal:646c8b8,'0.2E2',9(18)` for example. I need to show this value in a form.

So far I have:

```
f.input :image_prices, as: :check_boxes
```

Which will output in my view:

```
#<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0850>
#<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0710>
#<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB05D0>
#<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0490>
```

But when saving the correct ids are stored. The model relationships are as follows:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :image_prices, through: :image_options
end

class ImageOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image_price
  belongs_to :image
end

class ImagePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_options
  has_many :images, through: :image_options
end
```

I am so stuck at the moment and have tried for a good 3 hours now to no avail.

Comment: Three hours? Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. Please don't ask duplicate questions. Instead, read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Duplicates dilute the effort of those answering and frustrate them when their work seemingly didn't help. It also confuses those searching.

Comment: @theTinMan your comment is taken on board, will put it down to a bad day and will try harder next time to resolve on my own, though I am still confused as to why `<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0850>` was being returned, maybe you could assist ?

Comment: The question was answered in your selected answer. You have to provide a `to_s` method to output the value in a meaningful/appropriate way. Ruby has no clue what you want to see so it defaults to an `inspect`-type output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only problem is the image prices showing in the check box list as `#<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0850>`, just define a `to_s` method in your `ImagePrice` model and have it return a string representation of the price. For example, if the decimal value of that price is stored in a `price` attribute, your method would look like

```
class ImagePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def to_s
    price.to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: ok so that seems like the most simple solution ever :-), thank you so much. question though, how is `to_s` called when I dont use `to_s` in my form ?

Comment: `to_s` on a model instance is generally used by `simple_form` or `formtastic` to generate the labels for each element in a collection. If you're curious you can check out the source code for those gems. `simple_form` even has on option to specify which method to use for generating form labels.

Comment: thank you, that helps a lot, would you know why `<IMAGEPRICE:0X007F0431BB0850>` was being rendered ?

Comment: Ruby will use it automatically when interpolating a value into a string or appending to a string.

Comment: If you call `to_s` on an object that doesn't provide its own `to_s` method, the default return result is the object class followed by its id. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s